# what is attribute.specified for a DOM element's attributes?

Tags: dom, attributes

I just stumbled across something like this...

```
function(element) {
  ...
  var attributes = element.attributes;
  for (var index = 0, length = attributes.length; index < length; index++) {
    var attribute = attributes[index];

    // what is ".specified"?
    if (attribute.specified) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I'm looking at the W3C specs for a DOM Element, the Element interface, and I don't see `specified` anywhere.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-745549614

What does `attribute.specified` mean? What does it represent? Where is it defined in the specs?

Comment: Are you thinking of this?
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_attr_specified.asp

Comment: yes, that's what I'm talking about

Comment: I don't know where it's defined in the specs, but I found their definition to be pretty adequate:

The specified property returns true if the attribute is specified.

Returns true also if the attribute has been created but not been attached to an element yet.

Otherwise it returns false.

I believe it's on it's way to being depracted though.

Comment: Did this clear things up for you?

Comment: yea, I guess that makes sense now

Comment: can anyone give me any example when the specified property will return false? if it is not specified, it means that it does not exist? then I would not be able to use specified on null or undefined, cause it's attribute node's property. So what I know now is, what specified node means, but what does not-specified attribute node mean?

Comment: @Paweł [In the modern DOM, it is always `true`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-attr-specified).

Answer (score 3):

`<img src="kittens.jpg">`. the attribute is `src`, and its value is `kittens.jpg`. DOM elements are generic definitions. the actual attributes are specified by the actual language being used, e.g. XML, HTML, etc....

specified = the attribute has an explicit value assigned to it. e.g. the src attribute is specified, because it's been given the value kittens.jpg, but

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

the checked attribute is PRESENT, but not SPECIFIED.

Comment: No. `specified` just means the attribute is present in the original HTML or has been set by script using `setAttribute()`. `checked` in your example **is** specified. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/DM8Tr/1/. Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-637646024

Comment: hey Tim... do you mind creating an answer of your own with some more details?

Answer (score 1):

I have just found the information that attribute-node's property `specified` makes sense only for IE 6-7, because in IE 6-7 the `attributes` returns the collection of **all attributes supported** by the particular element node. Then you can use `specified` to find out if the attribute from the collection is attached to the element node. It will return false, if the element node does not have this attribute specified/defined. In modern browsers `attributes` returns the collection of the attributes **attached to the element** in fact, it means that every `attribute.specified` from the collection will return `true` in modern browsers. For modern browsers the `element.hasAttribute(attribute)` works the way, that `element.attributes[attribute].specified` works for IE 6-7.

Answer (score -1):

Different browsers have different implementations of the DOM and note that the implementation is in charge of this attribute, not the user.However, the user can change the default value of the attribute.

As for Chrome 54.0.2840.71 it makes every attribute.specified true, either it is in DOM specification or not, either it has value or not.
for Example,the attribute `__test` specified is always true in Chrome(version 54).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div __test></div>
    <script>
        var div=document.querySelector("div");
        var attributes = div.attributes;
        var attr_test=attributes[0];
        attr_test.specified=false;// "specified" is not writable and Setting it silently fails.
        console.log(attr_test.specified);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

so I agree that "it's on it's way to being depracted".

the "attribute.specified" is different in DOM level3 from DOM level2 spec.

1.same point

> True if this attribute was explicitly given a value in the instance document, false otherwise. If the application changed the value of this attribute node  (even if it ends up having the same value as the default value) then it is set to true.

2.Differences
"DOM-Level2" has more complicated judgement condition to decide whether the "attribute.specified" is true or not.
"DOM-Level3" says

> The implementation may handle attributes with default values from other schemas similarly but applications should use Document.normalizeDocument() to guarantee this information is up-to-date.

search `specified of type boolean, readonly` in
https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-637646024
vs
https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-862529273